# Add virtual field with doctrine query to symfony entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have a entity in my symfony project, that looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
...
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RestaurantRepository")
 */
class Restaurant {

    use TimestampableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $latitude;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $longitude;
}
```

I have now written a doctrine query in my EntityRepository to select restaurants plus the distance near an location ordered by the location. The problem is, that a get an array with results that looks like this:

```
[0] =>
  (
    [0] => distance1
    [1] => restaurant1
  )
[1] =>
  (
    [0] => distance2
    [1] => restaurant2
  )
```

I want, that the distance is a "virtual" field of a restaurant, so the result array should look like this:

```
[0] =>
  (
    [0] => restaurant1
  )
[1] =>
  (
    [0] => restaurant2
  )
```

My doctrine query:

```
$r = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
        $r
            ->select('l')
            ->addSelect(
                '( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . $cord['latitude'] . '))' .
                '* cos( radians( l.latitude ) )' .
                '* cos( radians( l.longitude )' .
                '- radians(' . $cord['longitude'] . ') )' .
                '+ sin( radians(' . $cord['latitude'] . ') )' .
                '* sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
            );
        $r->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
        return $r->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `$cord` and where does it come from? Some databases support virtual fields on the database level, but all the calculations must be done from other columns from the same row.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is possible just using the query. I had a similar task once and needed to loop over the result to set the virtual property:

```
$r = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
$r
    ->select('l')
    ->addSelect(
        '( 3959 * acos(cos(radians(' . $cord['latitude'] . '))' .
        '* cos( radians( l.latitude ) )' .
        '* cos( radians( l.longitude )' .
        '- radians(' . $cord['longitude'] . ') )' .
        '+ sin( radians(' . $cord['latitude'] . ') )' .
        '* sin( radians( l.latitude ) ) ) ) as distance'
    );
$r->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');

$results = $r->getQuery()->getResult();

//  need to loop over results to add the distance to the object itself
$restaurants = array();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    $restaurant = $result[1];
    $restaurant->setDistance( $result[0] );
    $restaurants[] = $restaurant;
}

return $restaurants;
```

One can argue if this type of logic should not be better put into a service class adding another business logic layer. To me at that time it was a valid solution.

I have used the distance field in a search that's why I needed it in the query. If you **just need the distance in the entity and do not use it in your queries** you can easily move it out of the repository and create an [Event Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) to set the virtual property.

Comment: Some other solutions - you can also use a Custom Hydrator if you really want a 'virtual' field in your object.  Another - if you just want the sorting but don't need to return the actual distance column, you could do `AS HIDDEN distance` and Doctrine won't return it in the results.  Then you could replicate your logic in the `getDistance()` method of your entity.